# Problem with exporting a plot with a legend to PDF

Tags: export, legending, pdf-format, linux

I've found a simple example that illustrates my problem:

```
ContourPlot[x^2 - 1 == y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

When I try to export this to PDF, I get the following:

[image: Contour plot with legend and bug]

and in the legend, the expression is misspaced and unreadable.  Is this a known bug?  Is there a known work around?

Comment: it worked for me. no problems.

Comment: What platform/version are you on? Works fine for me on Mac OS X Mathematica version 9.0.1.

Comment: Linux, mathematica 9.0.1

Comment: I could reproduce this on Linux, M9.0.1, but not on OS X.  You should probably report the problem to support at wolfram.com

Comment: On 10.1 and 10.3, I don't get any legend at all for this. I'll post a more considered answer this evening, if I get time.

Comment: When I try OP's code, I get no legend at all.  I can only get a legend if I am plotting more than one curve.  For example, `ContourPlot[{x^2 - 1 == y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]` gives no legend, but `ContourPlot[{x^2 - 1 == y, -x^2 + 1 == y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]` does give a legend.  Was this a change from version 9? I'm using version 10.2

Comment: `ContourPlot` does not show legend for equality, i.e. single contour line. However, it will if one uses `ContourPlot[{x^2 - 1- y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotLegends -> "Automatic"]`. Mathematica 10.3

Answer (score 4):

Funnily enough, when I tried this in version 10 (10.1 and the recently released 10.3), the legend didn't show at all. But in version 9 it does, and I assume that is what you were using given the timing of your question and the format of the graphic you posted.

I have not been able to replicate your problem in either Windows or Mac versions of Mathematica 9.0x. But I suspect that the issue was related to font embedding and substitution. Try the following code to remove the Mathematica custom fonts from the PDF, and use the normal text font for minus and equals signs.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}]
```